# Event handler for Disqus

Tags: jquery, disqus

I have implemented disqus and it works fine. I need to manually keep a comment count on my side. I planned to attach on disquss comment button, but without any success. I cant access it via DOM.

Is there any other way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a built-in callback:

```
function disqus_config() {
    this.callbacks.onNewComment = [function() { doSomething(); }];
}
```

Of course just replace `doSomething();` with your own script.